# Integer comparison fails

Tags: c

I have a linked list of a node structure, and in my function for searching through the list to find a node with a matching id the if statement seems to fail when comparing he passed in id and the node id. The if statement is on line 6 in the function below. Even if both *node_id* and *id* has the same value it fails.

```
NODE *node_id_search(int id, NODE *start) {
    NODE *result = NULL, *current = start;

    do {

        if(current->node_id == id) {
            result == current;
        }

        current = current->next;
    } while(current->next != NULL && result == NULL);


    return result;
}
```

node.h

```
typedef struct node {
    /*@{*/
    /**
     * The node id used to identify the node. The id is a positive integer.
     */
    int node_id;

    /**
     * The node type.
     */
    char node_type[10];

    /**
     * Pointer to the next node element.
     */
    struct node *next;
    /*@}*/
} NODE;
```

Comment: Try using printf and see what comes out?

Comment: `printf("%d==%d? %d\n",current_node->id,id,current_node->id==id);` just before your `if`.

Comment: Try `(*current)->node_id == id`.

Comment: how do you know it 'fails'? let me guess `result` is not set to `current`?

Comment: Turn your warning level higher. You should get a warning that the statement `result == current` has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Other than answers mentioned above(which I don't see how they relate to the question), the only problem I see is this piece of code:

```
    if(current->node_id == id) {
        result == current; //which should be result = current;
    }
```

Change it to:

```
if(current->node_id == id){
     result = current;
     return result; // no need to search any further(hence optimized).
}
```

---

Other than that,I don't see any problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is overly complicated. It can be reduced to:

```
NODE *node_id_search(int id, NODE *ptr) {

    for( ; ptr; ptr = ptr->next) {
        if(ptr->node_id == id) return ptr;
        }

    return NULL;
}
```

BTW: the above snippet returns the *first* matching node in the chain, where the original returned the last.

Also: if the pointer-argument ("start" in the original) were NULL, the original would dereference the NULL pointer and crash (or return nonsense). This version with the for(;;) loop would just return NULL.

Comment: the original returned NULL.

Comment: LOL. Yes that is true, I suppose I tried to reconstruct the OP's *intended* behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

2 points to be noted in the block

```
if(current->node_id == id) {
    result == current;
}
```

1. You're not checking whether `current` is `NULL` or not. If any node with `node_id` equal to  `id` does not exist, eventually you'll reach the end of the list (where `next` is `NULL`) and try to evaluate `NULL->next` and crash. Put a `printf()` before this block to see what happens.
2. You've written `result == current`, which does nothing on `result`. It's just checking for equality, and `result` remains the same forever. It should be `result = current`, which assigns the value of `current` to `result`.